# How can I include R objects like a vector into a DiagrammeR diagram?

Tags: r, object, r-markdown, diagram, diagrammer

How can I include R objects like a vector into a DiagrammeR?

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("

digraph boxes_and_circles {
# add node statements 
node [shape = box]
A; B;

# add edge statements
A->B

}
")
```

This works fine, but how can a include instead of the letters A and B a vector from R like this?

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 2)
A <- mean(x)
y <- c(2, 3, 5, 2, 3)
B <- mean(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the model string by pasting the parts together, and using node labels.

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 2)
A <- mean(x)
y <- c(2, 3, 5, 2, 3)
B <- mean(y)

library(DiagrammeR)

mod <- 
paste("
 digraph boxes_and_circles {
 # add node statements 
 node [shape = box]
 A[label=", A, "]
 B[label=", B, "];
 # add edge statements
 A->B
}"
) 

grViz(mod)
```